# Develop a web chat app using webrtc looking for any API for voice changing

Tags: webrtc, web-audio-api, javascript-audio-api

I'm developing a web chat app using webrtc I want to know that can we change the voice of the user live calling in webrtc and is there any API for live call voice changer so let me know thanks

Answer (score 0):

What you looking for is [insertable streams api](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Insertable_Streams_for_MediaStreamTrack_API). It allows you to access the media stream and apply transformations to the stream.

Check out [this example](https://webrtc.github.io/samples/src/content/insertable-streams/audio-processing/) which applies low pass filter on the audio track. There's a link to code at the bottom of the page.